# lambda inside subscript iterator

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, attributes, language-lawyer

Having a lambda in a subscript operator seems to be not working for g++ and clang.

Is this an implementation error or a "unhappy" rule in c++ standard?

Example:

```
class A
{   
    public:
        template<typename T> void operator[](T) {}
        template<typename T> void operator()(T) {}
};  

int main()
{   
    A a;
    a[ [](){} ];    // did not compiler: see error message
    a( [](){} );    // works as expected
}
```

Error:

```
main.cpp:13:6: error: two consecutive '[' shall only introduce an attribute before '[' token
     a[ [](){} ];
      ^   
main.cpp:13:15: error: expected primary-expression before ']' token
     a[ [](){} ];
```

I know that attributes starts with "[[" but I am wondering that "[ [" ( with one or more white spaces ) also works like:

```
 void func( int x [ [gnu::unused] ] ) {} // compiles fine! :-(
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is covered in [dcl.attr.grammar]. Having two consecutive `[` is an attribute, so you'll have to wrap in parantheses or do something else to make your intent clear:

> Two consecutive left square bracket tokens **shall appear only** when introducing an *attribute-specifier* or within
>   the *balanced-token-seq* of an *attribute-argument-clause*. *[ Note:* If two consecutive left square brackets appear
>   where an *attribute-specifier* is not allowed, the program is ill-formed **even if the brackets match an alternative grammar production**. *—end note ]* *[ Example:*
>
> ```
> int p[10];
> void f() {
>   int x = 42, y[5];
>   int(p[[x] { return x; }()]);   // error: invalid attribute on a nested
>                                  // declarator-id and not a function-style cast of
>                                  // an element of p.
>   y[[] { return 2; }()] = 2;     // error even though attributes are not allowed
>                                  // in this context.
>   int i [[vendor::attr([[]])]];  // well-formed implementation-defined attribute.
> }
> ```
>
> *—end example ]*

Comment: And is "consecutive" meaning with or without additional whitespaces?

Comment: @Klaus C++ isn't whitespace sensitive. `>>` was an exception in that that was considered a token, but there's no `[[` token.

Comment: Yesterday I learned that `template <> double B::var<double>=1.123; `is invalid, but `template <> double B::var<double> =1.123;`works. Only a whitespace... :-)

Comment: @Klaus `>=` is also a token.

Answer (score 7):

You have to enclose the lambda in parentheses. Otherwise the compiler considers two `[[` as introducing an attribute.

A similar problem can occur with using operator delete. For example you have to write

```
delete ( [] { return ( new int() ); }() );
```

or

```
delete [] ( [] { return ( new int[10] ); }() );
```

that is you have to enclose the lambda in parentheses.

Comment: Great to see these curious examples from other context. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap the argument with parentheses

```
a[ ( [](){} ) ];
```

Comment: Now idea how was first here :-): Nice to see a workaround. But anybody an idea this is intended by the standard? Fixing the start of attributes to '[[' would remove that problem. Thats why I asked if it is broken implementation or "unlucky" standard.