# Calling a specific overload of c++ insertion operator (>>) explicitly?

Tags: c++

So I have the following three lines of code that are bugging me:

```
int choice;
std::cin >> choice;
platform = platforms[choice];
```

This feels like it should be a one liner but I'm stuck on how to achieve it.

I was thinking of something like:

```
platform = platforms[(int)operator>>(std::cin)];
```

but obviously not exactly since the compiler wont have a bar of it.

Comment: `operator>>` returns a stream, it makes no sense to cast that to `int`. Don't think you can make that a one-line without a helper function.

Comment: Maybe `platform = platforms[ *std::istream_iterator<int>( cin ) ];`, but this would be UB if `operator>>` fails. So you should enable exceptions for `std::cin` to handle errors.

Comment: You code is very insecure - user can enter anything. What you want to do will only aggravate the situation. What goal are you trying to achieve? If to reduce the amount of code, then this is not the place where you should do it.

Comment: Thanks that code totally does the trick (if you were to put that forward as an answer I definately would like to credit it). - I'm aware how insecure the code is - its only for my own use while i'm writing some throwaway code.

Comment: Just for everyones amusement what I had come up with was 'platform = platforms[(int)[](){int choice; std::cin >> choice; return choice; }()];' ... thats the old OCD kicking in :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need an helper function to do that.

Thanks to lambda, you can do that in one expression:

```
platform = platforms[([](){int choice; std::cin >> choice; return choice;}())];
```

Comment: almost verbatem what I eventually came up with myself although the lambda does require an outer parenthesis or similar to break up the two consecutive left square brackets problem (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39411971/lambda-inside-subscript-iterator)  ... but then I spotted the snippet from the comment by zett42 which is much tidier.

Comment: parenthesis added.